# 100% container width for small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Is there a good way to configure bootstrap (with less) to set the container width to 100% for small devices (just like for xs devices) ?

I tried putting this in my css file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work (and I don't like it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you're using BootStrap with LESS, so I think that you can change its variables before re-compiling.

According to [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes) *every screen width (except the smallest) are assigned to specific LESS variables* and you should force `@container-sm:auto` in order to make it indipendent by fixed Tablet size.